# What's the right way to quit node.js after you've started a server?

Tags: macos, node.js

I'm developing a server-side node.js application. The problem is, after the server is started using `sudo node myfile.js` (without sudo it can't access port 80), I have no way to stop it except from using `sudo killall node` from another command prompt window, which seems wrong because it's laborous and won't activate the event `process.on("exit",callback)`.

Comment: `Control+C` will work fine.

Comment: @Brad it's not working fine here. It leaves the node process open and the next time I try to open it I get a port taken error.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should not used sudo if you don't absolutely have to. This causes the server to execute as root, thus everything it does is executed as root. This opens up huge security problems in the event of remote code execution (think recent Rails problems). An alternative that you can look at is running your node app behind a reverse proxy using something like nginx.

Honestly if you're just doing this localhost (which after re-reading you probably are) you're probably fine using sudo, however its something to keep in mind.

Comment: If `Ctrl+C` isn't working, then you need to figure out why as that should work.  Keep simplifying your program until that works to see what's causing it.

Comment: +1 for what @JohnnyHK said.  Your application is doing something to keep it running if a normal `SIGINT` won't stop it.

Answer (score 1):

For testing you can put a kill-switch in your program, like:

```
if(req.url=="/shutdown"){
    res.end("Shutting down server.");
    process.exit(0);
}
```

Then you just have to visit `http://localhost/shutdown` in order to shut down the server. You could even make an url that also launch a new instance for you, just don't forget to release required resources like files and the port in use first.

Answer (score 0):

Adding -9 to kill should solve the problem.

```
ps aux | grep node
kill -9 PID
```

Comment: But do I have to type this everytime I want to kill the process? I do it several times a minute. That would be overheady.